# How to update value of column based on other rows in the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have the following columns in my table:
`FolderPath`, `UserGroup`, `Permission`, `AccessControllType`, `FolderId`, `IsInherited`

[image: Database table]

I want to update the `IsInherited` Column if the `FolderPath` contains another `FolderPath` in the table AND the `UserGroup` is the same AND the `Permission` is the same.

How do I do this the fastest way possible?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I now have the following SQL-Statement. It is based on an answer:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.IsInherited = 'True'
FROM dbo.Folder t1 
INNER JOIN dbo.Folder t2 on t1.UserGroup = t2.UserGroup
    AND t1.Permission = t2.Permission
    AND t1.FolderPath LIKE  t2.FolderPath+'%'
WHERE t1.FolderId <> t2.FolderId
```

But when I checked the results they were not that what i expected. When a User has other Permissions to a lower level Folder the Field was also set to `True`. That is what's the problem.

Comment: Share with us the code you currently have. That will help people propose solutions that are close to your implementation (thus easier for you to integrate them in your code later on). Check how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @VictorZuanazzi I do not have some code yet because I do not know how to start.

Comment: I won't try to solve your problem cause you haven't shown any code. But maybe a self join can help you : https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-self-join/

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.IsInherited = 'Yes' -- Or use a bit field with value : 1
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN Table t2 on t1.UserGroup = t2.UserGroup
    AND t1.Permission = t2.Permission
    AND t1.FolderPath LIKE  t2.FolderPath+'%' 
    AND t1.FolderId <> t2.FolderId
```

This joins the same table when `Usergroup` and `Permission` is equal and the `FolderPath` starts with the same part.

Because it's an `inner join` it will only update rows that match this criteria.

If you wan't to toggle the state for all rows you could use:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.IsInherited = IIF(t2.FolderId IS NULL, 'No', 'Yes')
FROM Table t1
LEFT JOIN Table t2 on t1.UserGroup = t2.UserGroup
    AND t1.Permission = t2.Permission
    AND t1.FolderPath LIKE  t2.FolderPath+'%' 
    AND t1.FolderId <> t2.FolderId
```

Comment: `IsInherited` is a string field, so it will probably be "yes" or "no" (a bit type would indeed be more logical).

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I tried that solution and it somehow updated all of the data to 'Yes' and not only the ones that it should. I think that's the case because you join the tabe with itself and then every entry has at least one entry that matches. The exact same one as in the other table.

Comment: @Mikey please include a SQL Fiddle with sample data and include expected output for the sample data.